# How can I do an opening (hole) in the silicone with a diameter of 0.3 mm?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, material-science, home-experiment

How can I do an opening (hole) in the silicone with a diameter of 0.3 mm?
I need to have a perfectly smooth cylinder on the opening of the silicone with a 90 degrees angle with the base. Is it reel to use silicone injection molding? I can not delete any lay of silicone after molding. Any other variation? Silicone thickness up to three millimeters

Comment: Depends a lot on how deep the hole has to be. Photolithography, laser drilling, focused ion beam all come to mind...

Comment: Up to three millimeters

Comment: So, for home, how about a 0.3mm drill bit (in theory you can get them down to 0.15mm). Might have to buy at a hobby supplier. Now, the problem is how cold you have to get the silicone so that it will drill nicely, and how to do that without chipping. You will need a very good drill press.

Comment: If I must to do 5000 holes. Is it real to do it in a not long time?

Comment: If you really need to do 5000 holes you should be looking at something like photolithograpy. However, that could be very application dependent as to just what you are trying to do and why.